# How do you pass in an options hash without overwriting default options?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm new to Ruby (Ruby 1.9.3 / RoR 3.2). I wrote this function to create a gravatar.

```
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50, default: 'identicon' } )
    gravatar_id  = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    s = options[:size]
    d = options[:default]
    gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=#{s}&d=#{d}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: 'gravatar')
  end
```

Calling `<%= gravatar_for user %>` works. Calling <%= gravatar_for user, size = 30 %> causes the default option `identicon` to be lost. I assume this is because the hash in the method definition is getting overwritten by the hash I'm passing in from the caller.

How can I make it so that I can pass in *some* options while others default to what's specified in the method definition? I want to call `<%= gravatar_for user, size: 30 %>` and have it return a gravatar with size 30 and in the style of `identicon`, even though that argument was omitted from the caller.

Comment: Merging two hashes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980794/how-can-i-merge-two-hashes-without-overwritten-duplicate-keys-in-ruby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up a default options hash and then `merge` the options that the user has passed in to that hash. This will only overwrite properties that the user has specified, and leave everything else alone:

```
def gravatar_for(user, options = {})
  default = { size: 50, default: 'identicon' }
  options = default.merge(options)

end
```