# Merge nested hash without overwritting in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

After checking this [Ruby convert array to nested hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095077/ruby-convert-array-to-nested-hash) and other sites I am not able to achieve the following convertion:

I have this:

```
{"a"=>"text"}
{"b"=>{"x"=>"hola"}}
{"b"=>{"y"=>"pto"}
```

}

and I want to obtain:

```
{"a"=>text,
    b=>{"x" => "hola",
        "y" => "pto"    
    }
}
```

Until now the code seems like this:

```
tm =[[["a"],"text"],[["b","x"],"hola"],[["b","y"],"pto"]]

q = {}
tm.each do |l|
    q = l[0].reverse.inject(l[1]) { |p, n| { n => p } }
    i += 1

end
```

I tried with `merge`, but it overwrites the keys!. I tried also this [How can I merge two hashes without overwritten duplicate keys in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980794/how-can-i-merge-two-hashes-without-overwritten-duplicate-keys-in-ruby) but it keeps overwritting.

Update:

How can I do it for an undefined nested hash (level) ? `hash[key1][key2][key3]... = "value"`

```
{"a"=>"text"},
    {"b"=>{"x"=>"hola"},
    {"b"=>{"y"=>"pto"},
    {"c"=>{"g"=>{"k" => "test1"}},
    ...
}
```

Comment: The one who downvoted has no reasons. No research effort? I think my question is much better than this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415240/merge-ruby-hash. ANd this question has many up votes. Next time don't do it for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails there is the [`deep_merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/DeepMerge.html#M000954) function for `ActiveSupport` that does exactly what you ask for.

You can implement the same for yourself as follows:

```
class ::Hash
    def deep_merge(second)
        merger = proc { |key, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : v2 }
        self.merge(second, &merger)
    end
end
```

Now,

```
h1 = {"a"=>"text"}
h2 = {"b"=>{"x"=>"hola"}}
h3 = {"b"=>{"y"=>"pto"}}
h1.deep_merge(h2).deep_merge(h3)
# => {"a"=>"text", "b"=>{"x"=>"hola", "y"=>"pto"}}
```

Comment: With deep_merge works smoothly inclusive recursively. Thx

Answer (score 3):

You could use `merge` with a block to tell Ruby how to handle duplicate keys:

```
a = {"a"=>"text"}
b = {"b"=>{"x"=>"hola"}}
c = {"b"=>{"y"=>"pto"}}

a.merge(b).merge(c) { |key, left, right| left.merge(right) }
#=> {"a"=>"text", "b"=>{"x"=>"hola", "y"=>"pto"}}
```

Comment: This works very good, but I forgot to say that I need this for undefined nested level. This works for maximum 2 levels. I update my question.